# Activity.onDestroy behind the scenes And what does destroy really mean?

Tags: android, android-activity

It's familiar to me, that pressing back key will cause **activity** to get "destroyed", or when the developer calls function **finish()**, or when the system needs memory and etc...

And also familiar that we need to perform cleanup procedure in onDestroy like **unBindDrawables** ( see [example](http://www.alonsoruibal.com/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget/) ) for avoiding OutOfMemory Exceptions.

My question is:

> does activity's destroy mean that reference to **activity object** is removed? i.e.   activity object gets available to GC? If so why do we need to explicitly remove reference to activity's associated views?

Consider example:

If object **A** has a reference to object **B** and **B** is referred only by **A**, then if we nullify the **A**'s reference there's no need to explicitly set **B**'s reference to null, Both will GC-ed...

My intuition tells me that activity's case is something like this... Please tell me where is my mistake.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does activity's destroy mean that reference to activity object is removed? i.e. activity object gets available to GC?

Yes, insofar as Android lets go of the activity. If you have a reference to it (directly or indirectly) from a static context, it will not be garbage-collected.

> If so why do we need to explicitly remove reference to activity's associated views?

You do not "need to explicitly remove reference to activity's associated views".

Comment: Thanks in advance CommonsWare, I'm satisfied about first question.

Comment: But about second... Why then "unbindDrawables" is work-around to OutOfMemory errors? Or maybe I misunderstood the meaning of unbindDrawables?

Comment: @dioholic: Nothing in that blog post is absolutely necessary in general, though parts of it (particularly the background stuff) may be useful in certain scenarios. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7045044/115145.

Answer (score 0):

When you press back button your app isn't destroyed but paused and the SO calls the onPause() method.
It can be destroyed if the SO detects, for example, a low memory condition then it destroy and will call onDestroy method.
In this method you have to clean up threads (if you started them) or everything that is unnecessary anymore and cause the resource consuption.
If you are familiar with Servlet the onDestroy method in android is very similar.
Hope this help you

Comment: Pressing the back button calls the onDestroy(). Doesn't' it?